# Override style of webpage in webview - android

Tags: android, webview, screen-scraping

I am trying to override an existing style for a webpage in a webview. The following webViewClient has not effect on the webpage.

```
public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
}


@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

    view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('main-container').style.paddingTop = '10px';");

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the below jquery command to successfully apply the style.

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl("javascript: $('.main-container').css('padding-Top','40px')");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements. You´re not modifying each of them. You better move to jQuery or create a piece of code that runs through all the elements in the array and changes the properties you want

Comment: I tried this too :
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('main-container')[0].style.paddingTop = '10px';");

Comment: please, try with: `javascript:(window.onload = function() {document...})`

Comment: I was able to make it work with  view.loadUrl("javascript: $('.main-container').css('padding-Top','40px')");

Comment: post it as a response and validate it. I´ll vote u up